# Which operator is used first?

Tags: c++, operators

I have just taken a test in my c++ class and one of the questions I had gotten wrong is this:

> Look at the following statement.
>   while (x++ < 10)
>   Which operator is used first?

My answer was ++ however, the test tells me it is actually <. Could somebody explain why this is?

Comment: That's a badly worded question; what does *used first* mean? The value computation of the expression `x++` will happen first but the application of its side effect (incrementing the value of `x`) will happen after the computation of `x < 10`.

Comment: `operator++` means *increment and return **former** value*. It's a single operation and has a higher precedence than `operator<`. The test is incorrect.

Comment: It isn't actually significant. The value of x is evaluated, then that value is compared to 10 and x incremented, in some order which is basically immaterial. It would be material if x appeared on the RHS of <, but it doesn't.

Comment: there are 2 things: operator precedence and evaluation order. There's nothing being "used first" because that word definition simple doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. `operator++` has a higher precedence over `operator<`.

[C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

So, in this case, `operator++` will be called first, and then return the original value (before increment), which will be used for the comparasion.

[LIVE](http://ideone.com/QEH9bF)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Is it enough?

Comment: Note that (effective) operator precedence doesn't tell you an evaluation order. In particular the evaluation order is unspecified for function arguments, even when a function call is used as actual argument to another call, `f( a1, a2, g( a3, a4 ) )`. All that you can say here is that `a3` and `a4` are necessarily evaluated before `g` is called, which necessarily happens before `f` is called, but `a1` and `a2` can be evaluated before or after the `g` call.

Comment: For postfix `x++` for a built in type, all that's required for the `<` is the original value of `x`. Until some standards quote is presented that says otherwise, we have technically that the change of the value of `x` can happen before the `<`, or after it, because it doesn't matter for the result.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf According to the operator precedence, the expression will be interpreted as `X::operator<(X::operator++(int), 10)`, so I think the order should be guaranteed. For build-in type it should be also interpreted as the same function calling format, isn't it?

Comment: No. Built-in operators are not atomic wholes. Postfix ++ has two separate effects: producing original value, and modifying. The standard says that "The value computation of the ++ expression is sequenced before the modification
of the operand object", but that's all I see. Nothing about the modification being sequenced relative to anything. Indeed the standard goes on to note that "With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of postfix
++ is a single evaluation", i.e. this is not guaranteed in general.

Comment: It depends what 'used' in the ambiguous question actually means. The value of the postfix ++ expression is calculated before the comparison, but the side-effect may or may not be.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is because `x++` is a post-increment. So you could say that it first compared x to 10, and then afterwards added one to x.

Had it been `++x` then the add would have been done first.

I think it is a bit of a trick question, because in terms of operator precedence, `++` is higher in precedence than `<`.

Answer (score 2):

When `x` is of a type with user defined postfix `operator++` then the `++` is necessarily evaluated first.

For `x` of built-in type I'm not sure if anything can be said about the ordering.

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but note: `x++` will always be *evaluated* before the `<`. However, it is the *side-effects* of the `x++` that may happen before or after the `<`. Basically, it's `tmp=eval(x); return eval(tmp<10);` with a `++x;` at some random point.

Answer (score 0):

This is the priority order.

```
1  Parenthesis                    () []
2  Structure Access               .  ->
3  Unary                          ! ++ -- * &
4  Multiply,Divide,Modulus        * / %
5  Add,Subtract                   + -
6  Shift Right,Left               >> <<
7  Greater,Less than etc          > < => <=
8  Equal , Not Equal              ==  !=
9  Bitwise AND                    &
10 Bitwise OR                     |
11 Logical AND                    &&
12 Logical OR                     ||
13 Conditional Expression         ? :
14 Assignment                     = += -= etc
15 comma                          .
```